# Get state from multi screen to one screen?

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm quite new with React native. I want to set information include Add, Edit and Show detail on one screen, so I set state for each event when it's called.

When adding, I set isAdding, when editing, I set isEditing and when show details I set isShowDetail and navigate them, like this.

Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(ROUTE_INVOICE_DETAIL_NAME, { invoice, isEditing: true });
```

and Screen B (Details):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.isShowDetail = props.navigation.getParam("isShowDetail");
    console.log(this.isShowDetail);
    this.isAdding = props.navigation.getParam("isAdding")
    this.isEditing = props.navigation.getParam("isEditing");
    const { params = {} } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const { invoice = {} } = params;
    const { paid = 0, incurred = 0, transportFee = 0, id} = invoice;
    this.state = {
        id,
        invoice,
        isShowTicketDetail: false,
        customer: {},
        paid,
        incurred,
        transportFee,
        details: {},
    };
```

I don't know how to get `isEditing` and `isAdding` value, it returns undefined.

`ROUTE_INVOICE_DETAIL_NAME` is declared and I'm sure that it goes to Detail.

Comment: It looks like you're using react-navigation? I'd expect props.navigation.getParam("isEditing") to get you what you want. The getParam method is a helper, and you can also see all navigation params from props.navigation.state.params -- you might try to console.log(props.navigation.state.params) and see if what you expect is there.

Comment: Also, this is a style detail for you: But it looks like you sometimes set `isEditing`, sometimes set `isAdding`, and sometimes set `isShowDetail`. It wouldn't ever make sense for none of these to be set, and it wouldn't ever make sense for two or three of them to be set. I'd probably have a string param called `mode` or something, and set it to `SHOW_DETAIL`, `CREATE`, and `EDIT`. Then you don't need to check 3 different booleans, but can just check for 3 different cases of the one field.

Answer (score 0):

On Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(ROUTE_INVOICE_DETAIL_NAME, {
                    invoice_data: invoice ,
                    isEditing: true
                })
```

On Screen B you can get data like this :

```
let invoice_data = this.props.navigation.state.params.invoice_data
let isEditing = this.props.navigation.state.params.isEditing
```